# Ubuntu 20.04 second screen recognize with wrong size

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I search a lot and couldn't find an answer for this question also don't think it is connected with resolution.

I connected my second screen Acer ED322QWMIDX Curved (32 inches) to my laptop MSI GF63 8RC-039XPL 32 GB RAM/ 512 GB M.2 PCIe/ 1TB HDD. Graphic card NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile].

Below picture from display settings recognized as 24 but it should be 32 [Display tab second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa9d9.png).

The native resolution for both screens are the same and are 1920 x 1080 piksels

The view from my second screen is not sharp. Below picture:[Second screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3opPR.jpg).

Thx, in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Physical screen size is actually irrelevant to your display manager.

**The only thing that matters is screen resolution.**

You did not tell us the native screen resolution for each of your displays, but with modern panel displays, you should use only the native screen resolution.

Using anything other than the display's native screen resolution will result in everything looking "fuzzy" like your second picture.

Determine the native screen resolution for each of your displays and set the screen resolution accordingly.

Comment: The native resolution for both screens are the same and are 1920 x 1080 pikseli, then they are correct

Comment: In your screenshot you have selected 1920x1080**i**.  The **i** stands for interpolation and that is not what you want selected because it's not true 1080p.  You should select 1920x1080.  Furthermore you probably want to set the refresh rate to 60Hz.  Your refresh rate is wrong if this is really a typical 1920x1080 @ 60Hz panel.

Comment: set 1920x1080 @ 60Hz, it help a little but it is not what it should be it is still fuzzy

Comment: Can you take another picture?  Keep in mind that 1080p on a 32 inch display results in a very low pixel density of 69 ppi (pixels per inch).  By comparison, Apple "retina" displays are typically 300 ppi or more.  A low ppi is not something that can be fixed- it is a characteristic of the display. 1080p is not a very sharp screen resolution when it's stretched out over such a large area.